# How to query json typecode api with graphql?

Tags: graphql

https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts

GraphQl need root element but their is no root element.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to create a GraphQL server with a Query resolver to get this data. Try something like this

```
type Query {
   posts(...your post options): [Post]
}

type Post {
 ...your post keys
}
```

Comment: That means i cannot use GraphQL with rest api out of the box.

Comment: Correct. You can call REST server from your resolver but you have to have GraphQL backend in front of that.